# How to turn off the gradual update of UI changes in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation, performance

Basically I have a standard WPF UI that has listboxes, checkboxes, listviews, etc but when I change them, it takes a while for the change to appear. For instance, say I refreshed the bindings, the UI display isn't updated immediately. It takes a second or so say for the check boxes to appear to be checked, or unchecked.

Is this a setting that can be turned off?

Or is this because of Windows 7 Aero stuff? I use Visual Studio 2010 but it doesn't seem to behave like that even though that is WPF too.

Any ideas?

Comment: Honestly, it should be updating immediately. Does the screen hang in between updates (is something taking up CPU cycles)? Are you appropriately calling your "RaisePropertyChanged()" function whenever you update one of the values?

Comment: It's not that the app seems to hang but the UI change seems like an slow visual transition of one image into another.

Comment: What operating system and theme? And when you say a second or so, do you mean literally a second? A quarter second, I could understand, but not a second.

Comment: I would say at least half a second. To see just try it on a say ListView with checkboxes and the check and uncheck it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me as though you're just unhappy with the transitions in your system theme. You could [force a different system theme](http://arbel.net/2006/11/03/forcing-wpf-to-use-a-specific-windows-theme/) or override the default styles with your own.

Comment: Thanks this could be it. It's just the transition effect itself isn't very immediate. Otherwise the app is responsive.

Answer (score 1):

You say refresh the bindings.  Are you using binding to Properties with INotifyPropertyChanged?  This works fastest because only items that have been changed are updated.

Comment: Yes, but when I need to refresh the whole UI because the collections the UI is binded has to change, I update all the collections. But either way, whether it's a single check/uncheck, vs a whole update, the time is the same. Like I said it seems like a smooth transition, rather than a app hangup.

Comment: You can also use INotifyCollectionChanged.  This will let the UI know when an individual value changes rather than recalling the entire collection.  This is built in when using ObservableCollections.

Comment: Thanks I do that, but all the values in the UI is driven by values that I read and interpret from a file, when the user picks a new file, then I have to "reload" everything.

Comment: I did not have the right picture.  Maybe there are too many notifications.  Are you adding each record directly to the bound collection as you read in the file?